# How to test current probes

Tags: test

I have acquired high frequency current probes up to 5 GHZ. The current probes have a 50 ohm SMA-type output. The probe has a hole through its center where a conducting wire will be placed for measurement. I also have a signal generator up to 20 GHZthat I'd like to use for test. However i am not sure what the best test setup is. I was thinking to just create a simple series resistor circuit on a breadboard with an AC input. Am i completely on the wtong track ? what is the best way to test the functionality/performance of the probes?

Just for an idea, the probes I have are similar to the following:

http://www.vosssci.com/products/sensors/cp450/cp450probe.html

Comment: All you need to do is to create some current signal that you know how it looks like; if your funcgen+resistor setup can do that (I have no idea about the bandwidth of your resistor) then I see no problem.

Comment: How about a decent link to the actual probe and not a "something like this" link.

Comment: Decent link was not provided because it does not exist. They were special ordered for a custom application

Comment: @PlasmaHH are there high bandwidth resistors available?

Comment: @DeeTee: depending on what you mean by "high", yes there are

Comment: @PlasmaHH: up to 10 GHZ.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the circuitry you use, the important factor is whether you can provide **calibrated signals** to the probe.  For example, if you can provide a **range** of accurate current signals, over a **range** of accurate frequencies, then you know what you are providing as input.  Then, you will be able to determine the probe's characteristics, over the **range** being tested.